# Reviewing my reviewing

Tags: discussion, review

I was looking at my review history:  https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history

and noticed that in general my suggestions are not followed.

Posts where my recommendation is delete are not marked as closed, and posts where I recommend looks okay are closed.

Am I just a lousy reviewer or am I misinterpreting what is on the page?

And if it is so is there somewhere where I can check if I my recommendation was followed or not?

Answer (score 4):

Of course everybody occasionally makes a wrong choice in the reviews. But there is something that skews the review-reviewing and makes it systematically appear bad.

The reviews of posts that were subsequently deleted don't show up in the normal views. When I look at the [LQ review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) using a moderator-only view that filters out only your reviews, the first eight of the listed reviews where you recommended deletion, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/424690), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/424668), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/417687), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/417712), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/417578), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/417262), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/417064), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/414069) - I didn't look any further so far - are all deleted. Seems like a decent quota. But you cannot see those reviews, as far as I know. Since you have less than 10k rep, I'm not even sure whether you can see them following the links.

Roughly the same applies to the reviews where you voted to close and the question was subsequently closed and deleted, you cannot (easily) find those reviews (if you can see them at all), so what you see is skewed by selection bias.

All in all, what I saw so far of your review history does not look alarming.

Comment: I have about as much rep on SO as Williemien has here, 2K+. [This is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNH7n.png) in /review/low-quality-posts/history. The non-linked posts are deleted ones, the linked ones are not deleted. So, users do see the entire history of their reviews. (Also, everyone can follow the links you posted, even incognito visitors).

Comment: Thanks. So everybody can see deleted contents as long as they have a review link, good to know.

Comment: No, not the deleted content itself (it's reported as "not found"): just the review summary. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wlE2A.png).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again.